# Issues in converting sas macro to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sas, sas-macro

I am new to pandas, and I'm learning it through its web documentation. I am facing issues in converting the following SAS code to pandas.

My SAS code:

```
data tmp2;
set tmp1;
retain group 0;
if _n_=1 and group_v1 = -1 then group = group_v1;
else if _n_=1 and group_v1 ne -1 then group=0;
else group=group+1;
run;
```

*Note: In the above code `group_v1` is a column from `tmp1`*

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more succinct and efficient way to do this in pandas, but this approach quite closely matches what SAS does internally when your code is run:

```
tmp1 = pd.DataFrame({"group_v1": [-1, 0, 1]})

def build_tmp2(tmp1):
  # Contains the new rows for tmp2
  _tmp2 = []
  # Loop over the rows of tmp1 - like a data step does
  for i, row in tmp1.iterrows():
    # equivalent to the data statement - copy the current row to memory
    tmp2 = row.copy()
    # _N_ is equivalent to i, except i starts at zero in Pandas/Python
    if i == 0:
      # Create a new variable called pdv to contain values across loops
      # This is equivalent to the Program Data Vector in SAS
      pdv = {}
      if row['group_v1'] == -1:
        pdv['group'] = row['group_v1']
      else:
        pdv['group'] = 0
    # Equivalent to both retain group and also group=group+1
    pdv['group']+=1
    # Copy the accumulating group variable to the target row
    tmp2['group'] = pdv['group']
    # Append the updated row to the list
    _tmp2.append(tmp2.copy())
  # After the loop has finished build the new DataFrame from the list
  return pd.DataFrame(_tmp2)

build_tmp2(tmp1)
```